# Riemann Surface Tennis

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

So a few months ago I read Brave New World by Aldous Huxley and found the authors insights and style of humor remarkable. It describes a utopian society where people are conditioned to be enslaved by the pursuit of short term pleasure and happiness at the sacrifice of truth and beauty.

Some of the games people play in the Brave New World include electromagnetic golf, and my personal favorite Riemann surface tennis. Huxley went to Oxford so he must have had tons of really brilliant friends, but I think he's just taking the piss out of mathematicians and their magical powers of abstraction.

Still, what would playing tennis on a Riemann surface be like? Say for example, $f(z)=\log(z)$? What kinds of surfaces could you play Riemann surface tennis on? I'd imagine it'd be...challenging.

Comment: Isn't the earth a Riemann surface already?

Comment: Well I suppose so, but I was thinking more of objects on the human scale. If you wanted to use a sphere say, then opponents could stand on opposite poles and set up a net along the equator.

Comment: As for the physics involved...um, well that's why we use our imagination

Comment: This is a very interesting and diffficult question whose best answer would have been given by Thurston, who, alas, left us.

Comment: I think he wanted to write "Riemann's face"